# Generic test deployment items generated during build?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

How can I specify a generic test's deployment items to be files that are generated by the build process? My current understanding of the default build process template is that automated tests (edit build definition -> process -> basic -> automated tests) will run after the specified solution (I specify only one .sln file in edit build definition -> required -> items to build -> projects to build) is successfully built, but the executable wrapped by my generic test is a file written during the same TFS build.

Additionally:

1. The user triggering the new build does not have access or ability to edit the build definition
2. When creating or editing a generic test, users do not directly edit the XML and do not have permissions to specify deployment items located in the build folders of the build agent (using the file picker for deployment items in the generic test GUI)
3. I cannot use `DeploymentItem` attribute because this isn't managed code (please correct me if I am wrong about this)

I tried specifying a public (or otherwise user-accessible) drop directory (edit build definition -> build defaults -> copy build output to the following drop folder), and then specifying the generic test's deployment items from the drop directory, but I believe this does not help because the generic test is run prior to the build output being copied to the drop folder, and I also need the generic test to *not* run using an outdated copy of the wrapped executable previously existing in the drop folder from the output of a previous successful build, in the event that errors prevent a successful new build of the executable to be wrapped for the generic test.

Can this be accomplished through the use of environment variables or other variables available somewhere in the build definition or generic test definition?

<sub>(Copied and adapted from [my post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/01d2598f-6f68-4afc-8a9a-4b7358af86fe))</sub>

Comment: Do you need to configure this once, or do you need users to be able to specify custom deployment items for any build? What about using *.testsettings file with `Enable deployment` checked for running tests? You can select any file in this deployment, including files from mylib\bin\debug which are generated during build - why is it not work for you? Also, if you are using mstest, you can use DeploymentItem attribute for each test - will it work for you?

Comment: I need users with TFS commit permissions to be able to specify custom deployment items for any _generic test_ (which is done through the VS GUI or .generictest xml file). The generic tests are stored in the TFS repository as part of the team project. I am unclear what you are suggesting regarding `enable deployment` (I might be mistaken about what that option is for). `DeploymentItem` attribute is not an option for this task.